# jquery .find and .replace div background

Tags: jquery, background

Lets say I have two divs

How do I use .find to get div1's background image, than apply that background image to div2, and replace ".jpg" with "_highlighted.jpg" ?

```
var div2bg = $('.div1').find('div').attr('background-image'??)//how to assigned the background image as a variable?

$('.div2').css("background-image", "url(" + div2bg + ")");
$('.div2').css("background-image").replace(".jpg", "_highlighted.jpg");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close but replace returns a string, it doesn't change the source.

I think you want this instead:

```
var div2bg = $('.div1').css('background-image');

$('.div2').css("background-image", div2bg.replace(".jpg", "_highlighted.jpg"));
```

Comment: +1 - I didn't test, but that looks correct and exactly like the solution I was going to post.

Answer (score 1):

You an accomplish this with the following code:

```
// Get the first background image
var bg = $(".div1").css("background-image");
// Assign a modified version to another DIV
$(".div2").css("background-image", bg.replace(".jpg", "_highlighted.jpg"));
```

Whether or not the following is applicable to your project, you decide: I would like to point out this type of stuff is generally best handled with classes, and using jQuery methods like:

```
$(".div2").addClass("highlighted");
$(".div2").removeClass("highlighted");
```

It greatly reduces the verbosity of your scripts, and allows you to keep visual styles maintained in your CSS, rather than being partially-dependent upon values and strings within scripts.